# Cannot find R.layout.activity_main

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying to work out with multiple layout using some online tutorials. The thing is my program was building and compiling correctly as long as there was only one XML file. When I added multiple XML files, I am getting errors saying 'activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field' for the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

In fact, every item which I used previously in `R.*` is now reporting error. I don't know what went wrong. Can anyone suggest what needs to be done?

Edit 1: I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but that didn't help. Plus, I am importing the correct `R.java` file as in *mypackage*.R.java

According to @RubberDuck's comment, I as soon as I deleted the files again, the R.java file was being generated after building the project. However, when I create new XML files and add elements in it, build the project, R.java gets deleted.

Comment: What are the names & paths of the xml files you added?

Comment: did you clean your project after you added those files?

Comment: Have you tried to clean project and rebuild?

Comment: If your XML's contain errors your generated file might not build try erasing most of their content and making sure id's are not duplicated. if it works you can start adding stuff

Comment: @RubberDuck - That comment suggested some different approach. I had tried cleaning and rebuilding but that didn't help. Also, I imported the correct `R.java`. However, most elements in my XML files had the same ID as the one in other XML files. So, I tried renaming them. However, that didn't cause the `R.java`.

Comment: does a new project run on your eclipse?

Comment: Ya, it does run on Eclipse.

Comment: I got your tip, removing the R import. Great! So it worked for me and I didn't even need an answer. ;-)

Comment: If you have XML file in any different folder in the project, but lost the path connection, you can move your mouse cursor to the code error, choose "Create layout resource file 'main_activity.xml' then click ok, then you will see Layout folder will be created into your project tree, and there will be main_activity.xml file created over there. This is worked for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your XML's contain errors your generated file might not build try erasing most of their content and making sure id's and file names are not duplicated and no capitals and spaces are used. If it works you can start adding stuff.

Answer (score 109):

I had the same problem, fixed by replacing `R` with `com.example.appname.R` obviously put your package reference in there instead. Or just add this line to your file:

```
import com.your.package.R
```

Or even better, try removing this line from your code if exists:

```
import android.support.compat.R
```

Comment: There's an R.java file in the Android package. Unfortunately, using the Ctrl + Shift + O (eclipse) organize-imports command will usually grab that file, instead of the one in your gen folder.

Comment: try to clean your project. problem will be gone

Comment: Thanks man for saving my day !!

Comment: thank yoiu so much!

Answer (score 48):

Check if you not imported android.R accidentally.

Answer (score 26):

in 2019 I faced the same problem and I searched the internet and found the following which I am sharing with all.

In android studio letter R stands for the resources and this error occurs because of the build process not able to sync resources with your project. In other words, this error is caused when Android Studio can’t generate your R.java file correctly.
This problem happens when you shift code to another system or while building the android project for the first time. So when you create a new activity or new class you will see an error message like “cannot resolve symbol r” with a red underline.

Below you can find the possible ways to fix cannot resolve symbol r in android studio.

Update Project Gradle To Latest Version
Always use the latest version of Gradle to work android studio properly.

Sync Project With Gradle File
Once you update the Gradle plugin you need to sync project with the Gradle file.
Open android studio and click on **Files > Sync Project with Gradle Files option**.

Clean and Rebuild Project
The most effective solution is the simplest: clean and rebuild your project. Select **Build > Clean Project** from the Android Studio toolbar, wait a few moments, and then build your project by selecting **Build > Rebuild Project**.

Invalidate Caches / Restart
If you encounter this error after moving some files and directories around, then it’s possible that the **R.layout** error is being caused by a mismatch between Android Studio’s cache and your project’s current layout. If you suspect this may be the case, then select **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart** from Android Studio’s toolbar.
Issues with the names of your resources can also prevent the R.java file from being created correctly, so check that you don't have multiple resources with the same name and that none of your file names contain invalid characters. Android Studio only supports lowercase a-z, 0-9, full stops and underscores, and a single invalid character can cause an R.layout error across your entire project, even if you don’t actually use this resource anywhere in your project!

My problem and its solution:
In my case, I applied all the above but could not solve the problem. Thus I started a new project and pasted my code one by one and validated my code with running the app. Finally, at one point when I first deleted the code in colors.xml and copied and pasted code below in colors.xml file, I got the error.

```
<color name="bg_login">#26ae90</color>
<color name="bg_register">#2e3237</color>
<color name="bg_main">#428bca</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
<color name="input_login">#222222</color>
<color name="input_login_hint">#999999</color>
<color name="input_register">#888888</color>
<color name="input_register_bg">#3b4148</color>
<color name="input_register_hint">#5e6266</color>
<color name="btn_login">#26ae90</color>
<color name="btn_login_bg">#eceef1</color>
<color name="lbl_name">#333333</color>
<color name="btn_logut_bg">#ff6861</color>
```

when I undo my changes the error vanished again. Thus my code in colors.xml is not the code above and the code already in colors.xml i.e

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
<color name="bg_login">#26ae90</color>
<color name="bg_register">#2e3237</color>
<color name="bg_main">#428bca</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
<color name="input_login">#222222</color>
<color name="input_login_hint">#999999</color>
<color name="input_register">#888888</color>
<color name="input_register_bg">#3b4148</color>
<color name="input_register_hint">#5e6266</color>
<color name="btn_login">#26ae90</color>
<color name="btn_login_bg">#eceef1</color>
<color name="lbl_name">#333333</color>
<color name="btn_logut_bg">#ff6861</color>
```

"Maybe its because i did not have color primary defined"
Hope it will help someone like me who is new in programming.

Comment: **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart** worked for me.

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart always work (Y)

Comment: This worked for me Files > Sync Project with Gradle Files option, my Android Studio version is 3.6.1 [PrintScreen](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RWcxSwOMZto/XvUBJPOGhhI/AAAAAAAAOHY/WQNJJgoFvqYoF8qZGga5XljHnvsd9V3FgCLcBGAsYHQ/androidStudio_version.jpeg)

Answer (score 24):

what I tried:

1. check every XML file for some famous known errors.
2. cleaned the project multiple times.
3. synced Gradle with the project file.

What Worked:

**1. Invalidate caches and restart.**

Answer (score 9):

The stupid mistake I made to cause this error was to have the wrong **package** string in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I'd left the string set in the tutorial, but had used my own when setting up the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="COM.YOU.YOURAPPNAME"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Answer (score 9):

My error got removed by importing the line

```
import com.example.myapplication.R;
```

your import line may be different depending upon your project name in which my project name is **myapplication**

Answer (score 6):

You're importing invalid R class, 
import yourpackage.R class
for example
com.example.R

what actully happends that u import android.R class not yourpackages.R

Answer (score 5):

delete the following import if you have it

`import android.R`

this issue basically happen when you past a java code then you let android studio transform it to kotlin the import happen automaticly

Comment: Thank you.  This simple step worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Ivwd simply removed line  "import android.R;" and call Project->Clean...
That was enough for my on Win-7/x64 and Eclipse Kepler and last (02.2014) Android SDK

Answer (score 2):

You're importing invalid R class, check imports.

Answer (score 2):

goto tools->android->Sync project with gradle file
then click on S

Answer (score 2):

In my case , i accidentally imported my library's R. class not my app module's R. After editing this, it is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to resources are not loading properly and the similar issue can occur any view also so Below are some technics which you can use to remove this error:-

- Clean your project, Build -> clean Project
- Rebuild project, Build -> Rebuild Project
- Open manifest and check if there's any resource missing
- Check-in layout to particular id if missing add it
- If the above steps did not work then restart android studio with
  invalidating the cache.

**Note:** In the above-mentioned steps, the last step will work for this issue for sure.

Answer (score 2):

it happens when you change the project name

in my case, I just change

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xxxx.newName"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio go to `Tools` -> `Android` -> `Sync project with gradle files` or `File` -> `Sync project with gradle files` in latest Android Studio version.

Comment: **tools---->>>>>>android------->>>>>Sync project with gradle Files**

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an issue with the layout files, correct it and the auto generated class will appear.

Comment: Ya, even I think the same. However, I can't point out what the error is. I mean there is no syntax error. I really don't know what's going wrong. When I build i just get the message `Error in an XML file: aborting build.`

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions:

1. Make sure you don't have any other errors other than the R-related errors. Right-click your project folder in Eclipse, Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.

   2.Check to make sure you have the correct R imported. Sometimes the default Android.R can be imported.

   3.Check for errors in your layout XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@RubberDuck's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045118/cannot-find-r-layout-activity-main/57471371#comment22894233_16045118) and [@Emil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16045262/4390987) I was able to figure out what the problem was. The IDs of most elements in my XML file were exactly the same. So, I renamed each and every one of them. Also, my XML file contained capital letters. The filename should be in [a-z0-9_] so I renamed my files too and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem,

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

and restart :)

[Android adb not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571145/android-adb-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

or you can write

import.R.layout // at the top

It will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

I used maven as build tool, after I build my project and dig a lot in the internet to solution. My problem resolved by adding to the main_activity.xml

> tools:context=".MainActivity"

Answer (score 0):

I've got this when an inappropriate character (/-one slash) was added to the values/strings.xml, and, of course, renaming of problematic resource was helpful. 
And one more important thing - check the date and time on your device.

Answer (score 0):

JUST REMOVE the import.android.R;

Then the R.layout.(XML LAYOUTNAME) will turn to BLUE

IT TOOK ME HOURS TO FIND THIS ONE ERROR

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
It happened suddenly, after deleting some pictures from res. drawable.
I did two things.

- First I checked all my images in the drawable folder,if they all have preview. one of mine was damaged.
- Secondly, I closed all opened android studio and emulator. After that every things worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I removed import android.R and added
import android.support.v7.appcompat.*;

However this had to be done after importing
appcompat by right click project and import

Answer (score 0):

Happened once. Don't know the reason.

Build> Clean Project removed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Either your gradle or build need to know where resources are.

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning the project and syncing with gradle(no result), i removed all my import statement, and brought them back in using alt+Enter.