# Eclipse doesn't generate R.java

Tags: android, eclipse

I am writing a calculator app to familiarize myself with the ADK, but my project will not build. There is no generated `R.java`, and when I click build I get the following message:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'JakobCalculator'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I don't use subversion, so all of [These questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+pre+compiler+NullPointerException&aq=f&oq=android+pre+compiler+NullPointerException&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.4514&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which point to it as the problem don't help me.

The Eclipse console shows the following text:

```
[2013-04-20 10:42:54 - JakobCalculator] Android Launch!
[2013-04-20 10:42:54 - JakobCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-20 10:42:54 - JakobCalculator] Performing edu.us.jweisblat14.calculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-04-20 10:42:54 - JakobCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: using device '015d43637e60021b'
[2013-04-20 10:42:54 - JakobCalculator] Uploading JakobCalculator.apk onto device '015d43637e60021b'
[2013-04-20 10:42:54 - JakobCalculator] Installing JakobCalculator.apk...
[2013-04-20 10:42:57 - JakobCalculator] Success!
[2013-04-20 10:42:57 - JakobCalculator] Starting activity edu.us.jweisblat14.calculator.MainActivity on device 015d43637e60021b
[2013-04-20 10:42:57 - JakobCalculator] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=edu.us.jweisblat14.calculator/.MainActivity }
[2013-04-20 10:49:08 - JakobCalculator] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

I can't figure out what that XML error might be.
The only yellow warnings I can find anywhere are:

- on my `EditText` elements in the `MainActivity` xml (no label view points to them)
- on the xml declaration of the manifest (no grammar constraints).

Where might I find the error?

EDIT: here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.us.jweisblat14.calculator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="edu.us.jweisblat14.calculator.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What version have you changed to and what version was there before? Does it start working when you change it back?

Comment: Try running LINT on your project, it should identify your problem. LINT can be run by right clicking on your android project and pick android tools...

Comment: Can we see your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @user423199 LINT only finds the two errors referring to the `EditText`s.

Comment: @MaciejGórski I had a problem with specifying the number of columns in a `GridLayout` through the compatibility package, so I set the min version from Froyo to Jelly Bean. Since it's just an app for me to learn android, I don't need it to run anywhere execpt my tablet, running Jelly Bean.

Comment: @alex I updated the question with my manifest.

Comment: @JakobWeisblat where is your code..and full stack trace..?

Comment: @Pragnani my MainActivity? and where can I find a full stack trace? In Java I just copy/paste it from the console.

Comment: @JakobWeisblat There is also logcat, in which you can find red lines copy and paste them here

Comment: I was designing the layout before writing the code, so any code is just the default.

Comment: @JakobWeisblat But the `NPE` will occur in code

Comment: @Pragnani I don't find any recent (last ten minutes) red lines in LogCat, even though I just tried to compile.

Comment: I get a red X on any line in my MainActivity that references R, since eclipse doesn't generate an R.java. could that be a cause of a NullPointerException? I thought a NPE was calling an object that hadn't been constructed.
any remotely recent red line has nothing to do with this project.

Comment: just a small input: you sure the import of your R is the correct one and not the android.R or something like this?

Comment: @tenhouse the R.java is not generated, so eclipse wants me to import android.R; I had assumed that was wrong and that the problem was with R.java not being generated. Is that right?

Comment: yes from my viewpoint you're doing right. hmmm I really don't know then. I can just say the usual stuff, clean project etc. if all not works, maybe you try to make a new project and paste the thigns you've already done in there (file by file)..

Comment: Try creating a new project see if it runs. then start adding the xml elements one by one chances are that there are multiple id's etc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045118/cannot-find-r-layout-activity-main/16052283#16052283

Comment: I copied the over all the XML files that I had changed and it worked fine.

Comment: its the import android.R in the file if you do alot of copying and pasting during coding sometimes it throws it in your imports and throws everything off

Comment: Make sure all your resources are named properly (names with small letters, numbers and underscores only). Violating this rule prevents the system from building R.java correctly.