# Couldn't Resolve Resource File for new Empty Activity - Android

Tags: javascript, java, android

i'm Vito. I'm new in android studio..

[image: Click here for screen capture error :)]

When i want to make intent, i must generate new empty activity and when i generate new activity i have some trouble in : "activity_main4"

but i dont know why it's happening because it's occur often now always. is there any troubled in my program?

```
package com.example.jawaban_uts;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for reading my question, hope you can reply to solve my problem as soon as you can!

Comment: this happens sometimes in studio 3.5.1 just restart your android studio then clean & build project.

Comment: [try answers given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045118/cannot-find-r-layout-activity-main)

Comment: Check if the file res/layout/activity_main4.xml exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometimes in Android studio 3+. This solution is pretty simple. **Just close your project and import the project again.** You will see after the Gradle is sync successfully, the error will be disappeared.
**Reimport the project** and try.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because sometime android studio unable to find out new fields added in R class so you can sync,build or do invalidate cache.
I hope this solution will help you.

Comment: Thankyou reply my question! but i've resolved it with close and re-import project :D

Answer (score -1):

Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: thankyou for reply my question :D but i've resolved it with close and re-import project :D