# Why does my app keep crashing when I have 2 setOnclickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app keeps crashing when I set 2 `setOnclickListener`. The interesting thing is, when I only have 1 button intent, it doesn't crash. When I have 2 buttons, the new button does not bring me to new screen, and the old one just crashes the whole app.

Here's my code for the "old" button:

```java
SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intSignUp=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intSignUp);
            }
        });
```

If that's the only thing, then everything works. But when I add following, the new one doesn't work and old one crashes:

```java
Support.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent support=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Support.class);
                startActivity(support);
            }
        });
```

Here's the Logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference.
>
> at com.hoversfw.notes.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:96)
>
> And LoginActivity.java Line 96 is the beginning of Support.setOnclickListener.
>   Also, I have everything declared like:

```java
Support=findViewById(R.id.Support);
SignUp=findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Here's my XML file code:

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Already have an account? Sign in!"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Support"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
        android:text="Support"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/about"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

I also have all ID matched, Android Studio detects no error. I wonder what's causing the problem.

***UPDATE***

I have everything matched, like java file and xml, no ID is same, everything declared. And I don't think there is any problem with XML.

```java
SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intSignUp=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intSignUp);
            }
        });
        /*Support.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent support=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Support.class);
                startActivity(support);
            }
        });*/
```

If it's like above, then SignUp it works. If it's like

```java
SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intSignUp=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intSignUp);
            }
        });
        Support.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent support=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Support.class);
                startActivity(support);
            }
        });
```

Both of them doesn't work. (The difference is last one I commented Support.setOnClickListener..... but this one I made it as code.)

Comment: Maybe pasting the code of your xml file here could help

Comment: It seems you are trying to call the method `setOnClickListener` to a reference which is `null`. Either Support or SignUp is given a null value because `findViewById` can't find the reference to the object you wish to reference to.

Comment: Which one is causing the crash? Either `Support` or `SignUp` is `null`.

Comment: `SignUp=findViewById(R.id.textView);` Does your XML really define an id named `textView`? Should this be `R.id.SignUp` instead?

Comment: I updated information. Now it should be clear.

Comment: The only possible error left if you did declare Support as `Button Support=findViewById(R.id.Support);` or the button doesn't belong in your xml layout that you declare here `setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58387244/9382505) post.Your Android Studio just fails to find a newly added resource

Comment: But my Android Studio detects no error, and I don't see anything that's causing it. I've closed android studio and opened it several times but still won't work.

Comment: Check how looks your layout in design mode. Is it what you wont or with overlapping?

Comment: Nothing have same ID and overlapping.

Comment: Fragment or Activity which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm directly your error because you don't show your xml, but maybe you can do it.

1. you need check id view in xml same with you call in activiy with findViewById()
2. findViewById must above in your listener

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2 buttons, then you need to link them as button for both of them.

**UPDATED**

Since, you are using button and textview. I updated the answer.

This code at xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewSupport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Support" />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="SignUp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This code at Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Button buttonSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
    TextView textViewSupport = findViewById(R.id.txtViewSupport);
    buttonSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    textViewSupport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @RoboticReaper please check the answer. I already updated the answer

Comment: But like..what's the difference though? How will changing ID fix the problem?

Comment: @RoboticReaper it have lot of differences. When we use Textview in xml, we must use `TextView` class in java. It is linked with each other. It is working now?

Comment: But the problem isn't about button SignUp. It's the problem between textView "already have account? sign in" and Button Support. Both of them opens a new different screen. When there is only textView, it works. But when I add Support button, both of them doesn't work.

Comment: It's a textView. When I add the new button the textView doesn't work.