# Why can't i find the layout I have created my MainActivity.java file?

Tags: java, android

I was following the instructions online in android app development course for beginners and I encountered this problem.

The instructor was demonstrating how we could use the layouts we created for the activity. He was able to find the layout he created using `R.layout.`, but I could not.

The `activity_main_listview.xml` is the View that I created. I am an absolute beginner so I don't know what is wrong here.

Is there any way I could resolve this problem?

I have tried to Synchronize both the `.xml` files and the `MainActivity.java` file. I have also tried to clean and rebuild the project.

[This is a picture of the part where it did not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlMai.png)

Comment: Sometime it happens. Just close and restart AndroidStudio.

Comment: File->Invalidate caches/restart

Comment: change you xml layout name the find it. Hope it will work

Comment: check this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16748169/7271027](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16748169/7271027)

Comment: invalidate and restart your android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common problem which occurs with Android Studio!

Its not your problem, it is bug of Android Studio!

To resolve this, Just **Clean your project** and **Restart Android Studio!**

Comment: If it works make sure you mark it as useful so that other developers gets benefit of this!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed by replacing R with com.example.appname.R obviously put your package reference in there instead. Or just add this line to your file:

```
import com.testapp.activitydemo.package.R
```

Or even better, try removing this line from your code if exists:

```
import android.support.compat.R
```

If your XML's contain errors your generated file might not build try erasing most of their content and making sure id's and file names are not duplicated and no capitals and spaces are used. If it works you can start adding stuff.

Another note:

Sync Project With Gradle File Once you update the Gradle plugin you need to sync project with the Gradle file. Open android studio and click on **Files > Sync Project with Gradle Files option.**

Clean and Rebuild Project The most effective solution is the simplest: clean and rebuild your project. Select **Build > Clean** Project from the Android Studio toolbar, wait a few moments, and then build your project by selecting **Build > Rebuild Project.**